# Autocolor for italic and bold fonts in pandoc-template

Tags: sectioning, color, bold, pandoc, italic

I have started using pandoc to auto-generate PDFs from my .md-notes. This is working out so far, I succeeded to customize the font, background etc. For readability, I want all the italic parts as well as all the bold parts in my document to be highlighted with a different color. I am using a latex template to format the produced pdf, but I don't know how to autocolor italic or bold parts. The same goes for sections or subsections.

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful. Thanks a bunch and goodbye!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are multiple ways to solve this, the comment suggested above works well.

What also works is:

```
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}[
ItalicFeatures={Color=olive},
BoldFeatures={Color=orange},
]
```

This did the trick for me. I went with this option as I wanted to change the font as well.

Comment: This works, but every time I use bold or italic and go back to normal, the color goes back to black for the rest of the paragraph instead of the white I chose for the whole thing. That is kinda weird and I don't know why it happens. If I  declare a default color, it works my section headings instead become white which they shouldn't. So I either have to explicitly change colors on sections or set the default font color for normal text which I don't know how to do since I can't find the documenation on `\setmainfont`

Answer (score 2):

Pandoc uses `\emph` for emphasized text and `\textbf` for strongly emphasized text. You can include the code in your template or redefine the commands in a YAML `header-includes` section:

```markdown
---
header-includes:
  - \let\emphasized\emph
  - \let\strong\textbf
  - \renewcommand{\emph}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\emphasized{#1}}}
  - \renewcommand{\textbf}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\strong{#1}}}
---

The following will be *red*.

Strong will be **blue**.
```

The Overleaf [docs on colours](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Using_colours_in_LaTeX) can serve as a good introduction.